# extreme points of unit ball in a normed space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In Royden and Fitzpatrick's Real Analysis book, they have the following exercise:

Show that the only possible extreme points of the closed unit ball in a normed vector space have norm $1$.

(To paraphrase, if $\|x\|\leq 1$ is an extreme point of the closed unit ball in a normed vector space, then $\|x\|=1$. Note that the assertion does not say that all unit vectors are extreme points.)

I tried proving this for a finite-dimensional vector space, but even that case I couldn't prove although ``intuitively'' it kind of make sense. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fix $e\neq 0$ and write any $x$ with $\|x\|<1$ as $\frac {(x+\epsilon e)+(x-\epsilon e)} 2$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I tried doing that but I couldn't guarantee that the perturbations stay inside the unit ball

Comment: actually i think i figured it out